# (Question about 'final' and) How do I access the list object contents of 'myModels' from the Spring ModelMap in JSTL?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final String index(final ModelMap model)
{
      List myModels = ArrayList<MyModel>(getMyModels());
      model.addAttribute("mymodel", myModels);
      return "index";
}
```

1. In Spring I put the `myModels` list into the `ModelMap` to be passed to the "index" view. How do I then access those `MyModel` objects from the JSTL code?
2. Is it necessary for this controller method to be `final` and for the `ModelMap` parameter to be `final`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. By name, e.g `<c:out value="${mymodel}"/>`. Every model attribute you add to the `ModelMap` is made available as a JSP request-scoped attribute.
2. "no" and "no", `final` is irrelevant here - did someone tell you otherwise?

Comment: @peasoap: Spring doesn't care either way, it looks like an ill-advised stylistic choice by the author.